# How to correcttly size text for different android screens using multiple views, where to store views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I understand that in order for my app to look the same on multiple devices I need to have multiple views depending on the screen size.

can I store these new views in the given drawable folders or should I create new folders where the exsisting layout folder is like this:-

layout-ldpi
layout-mdpi
layout-hdpi
layout-xhdpi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. views you may save in **drawables** folder
2. If a layout from the default **layout** folder does not fit certain screens you redefine the new layout
   in a new folder using qualifier ([details](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html)) i.e layout-large accordingly and refer to the views defined in drawables folder 
   here. When defining layout's elements size dont use plain number, instead declare them possibly in separate files in **values** related folders.
3. Define numeric values in **values** folder and redefine them if necessary by creating additional folders
   following the same logic as with layouts, such as **values-large**. In this logic for large screens 
   android will refer to **folder_basic_name-large** format for accessing layout design and parameters.

Comment: Ahh thanks eldjon, i thought the ldpi type folders would work but i think because one of my test devices is a galaxy tab 2 with 7.0 inch screen( which i think is pretty old) using the small-medium and large qualifiers will work.

Comment: dpi related folders refer only to screens density.